# Instantiate subclasses by name

Tags: python-3.x

Consider the following example:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Base(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def say(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def from_config(cls, config):
        kind = config['kind']
        # TODO: Look at all subclasses, find one with matching kind
        # TODO: and call its constructor with **config['parameters']


class ChildA(Base):
    kind = 'A'

    def say(self):
        return 'Hello, I am A'


class ChildB(Base):
    kind = 'B'

    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__()
        self._name = name

    def say(self):
        return 'Hello, I am {}'.format(self._name)


def main():
    configA = {
        'kind': 'A',
        'parameters': {}
    }
    configB = {
        'kind': 'B',
        'parameters': {
            'name': 'Foo'
        }
    }
    print(ChildA(**configA['parameters']).say())
    print(ChildB(**configB['parameters']).say())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I want to implement a class method in `Base` that looks at all of its subclasses (and possibly their subclasses, ad infinitum), and calls the correct constructor with `**config['parameters']` according to a matching `kind`, i.e., `cls.kind == config['kind']`.

My questions are:

- Can I use `__subclasses__` to achieve this?
- What happens if the class definitions reside in different modules?

Comment: I have several ideas, but the answer depends on what really want: `Base.from_string(config)` - and get an object of correct class, am I got it right? I.e if `config['kind'] == 'A'` it should instantiante `ConfigA`

Comment: @MikhailStepanov That's true.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forget about the second question, I'll edit

Comment: Also you can use _dunder_  `__name__` which equals a class' name instead of `kind` -  so kind is unnecessary. May be kind is required somewhere else, but if you omit it, you'll write and maintain less code (`__name__` is for free)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use a following config dictionaries in examples:

```
configA = {
    'kind': 'A',
    'parameters': {}
}

configB = {
    'kind': 'B',
    'parameters': {
        'name': 'Foo'
    }
}

configC = {
    'kind': 'C',
    'parameters': {
        'age': '17'
    }
}

configD = {  # ChildD inherits from both ChildC, ChildA
    'kind': 'D',
    'parameters': {
        'name': 'Bar',
        'age': '17'
    }
}
```

For the first question the answer is 'yes'. You can iterate recursively through the `__subclasses__`, if they exists. I define `extract_all_subclasses` as a function, because it can work for (aprroximately any) class.

```
def extract_all_subclasses(cls):
    output = set() 
    # I use the set to avoid repeating classes in case of multiple inheritance -
    # but lists is possible alternative, just filter it later
    subclasses = set(cls.__subclasses__())
    output = output.union(subclasses)
    for subcls in subclasses:
        if subcls.__subclasses__():  # if there's some subclasses
            for subcls_inner in subcls.__subclasses__():
                output = output.union(extract_all_subclasses(subcls))
        else:  # just append 
            output = output.union(subclasses )
    return output
```

on the `Base`:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Base(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def say(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def from_config(cls, config):
        subclasses = extract_all_subclasses(cls)  # extracting all the subclasses
        subcls = {c.kind: c for c in subclasses}[config['kind']]  # get one from dictionary
        return subcls(**config['parameters'])
```

for now there's no subclasses:

```
extract_all_subclasses(Base)
Out:
set()
```

But then:

```
class ChildA(Base):
    kind = 'A'

    def say(self):
        return 'Hello, I am A'


class ChildB(Base):
    kind = 'B'

    def __init__(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
        self._name = name

    def say(self):
        return 'Hello, I am {}'.format(self._name)

class ChildC(ChildB):
    kind = 'C'

    def __init__(self, age, *args, **kwargs):
        self._age = age

    def say(self):
        return 'Hello, I am Base\'s grandson, my age is {}'.format(self._age)

class ChildD(ChildC, ChildA):
    kind = 'D'

    def __init__(self, age, name):
        self._age = age
        self._name = name

    def say(self):
        return 'Hello, I am Base\'s grandson, my age is {} and my name is {}'.format(self._age, self._name)

extract_all_subclasses(Base)
Out:
{__main__.ChildA, __main__.ChildB, __main__.ChildC, __main__.ChildD}
```

So, it works fine even in case of the multiple inheritance. Check it out:

```
print(Base.from_config(configA).say())
print(Base.from_config(configB).say())
print(Base.from_config(configC).say())
print(Base.from_config(configD).say())
Out:
Hello, I am A
Hello, I am Foo
Hello, I am Base's grandson, my age is 17
Hello, I am Base's grandson, my age is 17 and my name is Bar
```

**NB!** I just removed calls to the superclass's constructor, because it can cause an error, if it expects an argument which you don't provide or if you provide an unexoected argument ot it. But it's dangerous only in cases of nested subclasses and it's easy to avoid. And I dont't get the idea why you need them - if you redefine the behaviour on `__init__` (may be it's just simplification).

Example of possible error (the `Base` is the same):

```
class ChildA(Base):
    kind = 'A'

    def say(self):
        return 'Hello, I am A'


class ChildB(Base):
    kind = 'B'

    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__()
        self._name = name

    def say(self):
        return 'Hello, I am {}'.format(self._name)


class ChildC(ChildB):
    kind = 'C'

    def __init__(self, age):
        super().__init__()
        self._age = age

    def say(self):
        return 'Hello, I am Base\'s grandson, my age is {}'.format(self._age)

print(Base.from_config(configA).say())
print(Base.from_config(configB).say())
print(Base.from_config(configC).say())
Out:
Hello, I am A
Hello, I am Foo

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
<ipython-input-4-6932e3173d3f> in __init__(self, age)
     21 
     22     def __init__(self, age):
---> 23         super().__init__()
     24         self._age = age
     25 

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

**Edit**
Adressing the latter question, yes, but with a restrictions. You can structure your project as usual, but if you wish it working, you shoul import child classes into namespace. Otherwise it won't work.

I use the following structure:

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── a.py
├── b.py
├── base.py
├── c.py
├── d.py
├── extractor.py
└── main.py
```

where base.py is the definition of the `Base`, a.py, b.py, c.py, d.py - definitions of `ChildA`, `ChildB`, `ChildC`, `ChildD`, extractor is a **subclasses** extractor function, and main has the following listing:

```
from subclasses.base import Base
from subclasses.a import ChildA
from subclasses.b import ChildB
from subclasses.c import ChildC
from subclasses.d import ChildD

config = [
    {
        'kind': 'A',
        'parameters': {}
    },
    {
        'kind': 'B',
        'parameters': {
            'name': 'Foo'
        }
    },
    {
        'kind': 'C',
        'parameters': {
            'age': '17'
        }
    },
    {  # ChildD inherits from both ChildC, ChildA
        'kind': 'D',
        'parameters': {
            'name': 'Bar',
            'age': '17'
        }
    }
]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(
        [
            Base.from_config(cfg).say() for cfg in config
        ]
    )
```

- it works just as planned. But if I omit the imports of `ChildX` - it raises a KeyError - because that case Childs were not imported and `extract_all_subclasses` can't extract them - they don't exist.